# Why is my travis-ci build status always reflected as unknown?

Tags: travis-ci, github-services

I setup travis-ci for a new [rails project](https://github.com/briandavidwetzel/white_dog), but for some reason the build status is always shown as unknown in my README. I have googled a bit and not been able to find any solutions.  Although I have had some similar symptoms as others. E.g., [all of my builds](http://travis-ci.org/#!/briandavidwetzel/white_dog) show they are still building, but if you look at the individual builds they are passed or failed.

BTW, should this be reported as a travis-ci issue?

Comment: Best to contact *them* directly. Stackoverflow is not a support forum for services and the travis-ci people are pretty speedy when they know about issues.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I ran in to the same issue. I was able to address the issue by adding the `branch` parameter to the image url:

**This url did not work**

```
https://travis-ci.org/kandadaboggu/iprofiler.png
```

**This url worked**

```
https://travis-ci.org/kandadaboggu/iprofiler.png?branch=master
```

Comment: This would be the correct answer, we have later changed our web interface to give links with the branch parameter set.

Answer (score 3):

**.com will not work here, as per latest. This works for me**

```
## Travis-Build
[![Build Status](https://api.travis-ci.org/sananand007/genTspsolver.png?branch=master)](https://travis-ci.org/sananand007/genTspsolver)
```

> ### Travis-Build
>
> [image: Build Status]

Comment: As of April 5th of 2020, this should be the right answer.

Comment: so just adding  a png nothing special.

Answer (score 2):

I use the Travis badge in our project's README in Github and I had the same issue. It turned out I did not have the correct settings in Travis.

From your Travis dashboard, go to More options => Settings.  For me, I needed to turn on "Build pushed branches." After that, I clicked More options => Trigger build, and triggered a build.

Once Travis ran (and passed), I went back to Github and hard refreshed the page. The Travis badge had updated to green, or "build: passing".

Comment: Yeah, but if you use the wrong URL as mentioned in the answers above, the badge will only stay green for a while (cache timeout?) and then will revert back to build failed...

Answer (score 2):

In my case, the links I used were based on travis-ci.org when as of May 2018, all links should use travis-ci.com

See [this announcement](https://blog.travis-ci.com/2018-05-02-open-source-projects-on-travis-ci-com-with-github-apps)

**This registered unknown**

`https://travis-ci.org/jlboat/FastaUtils.png?branch=master`

**This registered passing**

`https://travis-ci.com/jlboat/FastaUtils.png?branch=master`

Answer (score 0):

My issue was just that I this was my first build on travis-ci.org after I made my app public instead of private.  I just had to wait for the image to be updated to reflect the new build status, which took a couple minutes.  It is a free service on the .org rather than the paid service on the travis-ci.com so we have to wait on the shared resources to create the build status image.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the issue resolved by opening the `image url` on browser. You can get the `image url` from the `Status Image` popup by clicking build status badge on your project dashboard. The build status changed immediately after the `image url` fully loaded on the browser. For example [click me](https://api.travis-ci.org/yohaneslumentut/ng-ripple-module.svg?branch=master)

Answer (score 0):

Follow a simple rule: use link of your travis repository dashboard.
In my case it's `https://travis-ci.com/<username>/<repository>`